# how to solve status code 429 on hitting an instagram api with axios

Tags: instagram-graph-api

***Update:-*** I tested it on ios It is giving the response but on android it is giving status 429

I am trying to hit API of instagram to get json data from it by appending `__a=1` in the Instagram URL to get the download link of the video url. But it is giving me error with status code 429. But in Postman it is working and also giving me the reosponse as well in json format. Can anyone please help me here , How can I solve it.

Here is the response I am getting using postman
[image: Postman Response Screenshot]

Here is my sample code

```js
    import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
    import {
      SafeAreaView,
      StyleSheet,
      ScrollView,
      View,
      Text,
      StatusBar,
    } from 'react-native';
    
    import axios from 'react-native-axios';
    
    const App = () => {
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hereeeee');
    
        async function fetchMyAPI() {
          //Make a request for a user with a given ID
    
          await axios
            .get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CK9OlOgK73g/?__a=1')
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    
        fetchMyAPI();
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
          <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}>
              <Text>check this screen</Text>
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
    
    export default App;
```

Headers I am getting on Status 429

```
{"config": {"data": undefined, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "error"}, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": {"0": [Function transformRequest]}, "transformResponse": {"0": [Function transformResponse]}, "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/CK9OlOgK73g/?__a=1", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\" class=\"no-js not-logged-in \">
    <head>
        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
        <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">

        <title>
                  Page Not Found &bull; Instagram
                </title>


        <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noimageindex, noarchive\">
        <meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style\" content=\"default\">
        <meta name=\"mobile-web-app-capable\" content=\"yes\">
        <meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#ffffff\">
        <meta id=\"viewport\" name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover\">
        <link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"/data/manifest.json\">





        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        (function() {
  var docElement = document.documentElement;
  var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\\\s)no-js(\\\\s|$)');
  var className = docElement.className;
  docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
})();
</script>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
(function() {
  if ('PerformanceObserver' in window && 'PerformancePaintTiming' in window) {
    window.__bufferedPerformance = [];
    var ob = new PerformanceObserver(function(e) {
      window.__bufferedPerformance.push.apply(window.__bufferedPerformance,e.getEntries());
    });
    ob.observe({entryTypes:['paint']});
  }

  window.__bufferedErrors = [];
  window.onerror = function(message, url, line, column, error) {
    window.__bufferedErrors.push({
      message: message,
      url: url,
      line: line,
      column: column,
      error: error
    });
    return false;
  };
  window.__initialData = {
    pending: true,
    waiting: []
  };
  function asyncFetchSharedData(extra) {
    var sharedDataReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sharedDataReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (sharedDataReq.readyState === 4) {
            if(sharedDataReq.status === 200){
              var sharedData = JSON.parse(sharedDataReq.responseText);
              window.__initialDataLoaded(sharedData, extra);
            }
          }
        }
    sharedDataReq.open('GET', '/data/shared_data/', true);
    sharedDataReq.send(null);
  }
  function notifyLoaded(item, data) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.data = data;
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].resolve(item.data);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  function notifyError(item, msg) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.error = new Error(msg);
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].reject(item.error);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  window.__initialDataLoaded = function(initialData, extraData) {
    if (extraData) {
      for (var key in extraData) {
        initialData[key] = extraData[key];
      }
    }
    notifyLoaded(window.__initialData, initialData);
  };
  window.__initialDataError = function(msg) {
    notifyError(window.__initialData, msg);
  };
  window.__additionalData = {};
  window.__pendingAdditionalData = function(paths) {
    for (var i = 0;i < paths.length; ++i) {
      window.__additionalData[paths[i]] = {
        pending: true,
        waiting: []
      };
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataLoaded = function(path, data) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyLoaded(window.__additionalData[path], data);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data loaded \"' + path + '\"');
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataError = function(path, msg) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyError(window.__additionalData[path], msg);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data encountered an error \"' + path + '\": ' + msg);
    }
  };

})();
</script><script type=\"text/javascript\">

/*
 Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the \"License\");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an \"AS IS\" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/

(function(){function g(a,c){b||(b=a,f=c,h.forEach(function(a){removeEventListener(a,l,e)}),m())}function m(){b&&f&&0<d.length&&(d.forEach(function(a){a(b,f)}),d=[])}function n(a,c){function k(){g(a,c);d()}function b(){d()}function d(){removeEventListener(\"pointerup\",k,e);removeEventListener(\"pointercancel\",b,e)}addEventListener(\"pointerup\",k,e);addEventListener(\"pointercancel\",b,e)}function l(a){if(a.cancelable){var c=performance.now(),b=a.timeStamp;b>c&&(c=+new Date);c-=b;\"pointerdown\"==a.type?n(c,
a):g(c,a)}}var e={passive:!0,capture:!0},h=[\"click\",\"mousedown\",\"keydown\",\"touchstart\",\"pointerdown\"],b,f,d=[];h.forEach(function(a){addEventListener(a,l,e)});window.perfMetrics=window.perfMetrics||{};window.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=function(a){d.push(a);m()}})();
</script>
                <link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"76x76\" href=\"/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/666282be8229.png\">
                <link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"120x120\" href=\"/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png/8a5bd3f267b1.png\">
                <link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"152x152\" href=\"/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png/68193576ffc5.png\">
                <link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"167x167\" href=\"/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-167x167-precomposed.png/4985e31c9100.png\">
                <link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"180x180\" href=\"/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-180x180-precomposed.png/c06fdb2357bd.png\">

                    <link rel=\"icon\" sizes=\"192x192\" href=\"/static/images/ico/favicon-192.png/68d99ba29cc8.png\">



                    <link rel=\"mask-icon\" href=\"/static/images/ico/favicon.svg/fc72dd4bfde8.svg\" color=\"#262626\">

                  <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"/static/images/ico/favicon.ico/36b3ee2d91ed.ico\">




        <style type=\"text/css\">/* @generated
 * DO NOT CHANGE THIS FILE. Instead, modify the non-build version of \"main.css\"
 * then run \"yolo css\"
 */
body{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;background-color:#fafafa;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,\"Segoe UI\",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0}.client-root{font-size:14px}a{text-decoration:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__{height:100vh}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{margin-top:137px;position:relative}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{display:block;margin-top:0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root__{background-color:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;height:77px;position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;z-index:100}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__profilePic__{display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__username__{color:#003569;display:inline!important;float:right;font-weight:400;margin-right:2px;margin-top:12px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn__{display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right:2px;margin-top:12px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText__{color:#003569;font-weight:400}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{background-image:url(/static/images/branding/logoWhiteoutLockup.png/3a62b1a95da3.png);background-size:100%;height:35px;left:16px;position:absolute;text-indent:-9999em;top:6px;width:176px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__ a{display:block;height:100%;width:100%}@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),screen and (min-resolution:1.5dppx){.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{background-image:url(/static/images/branding/logoWhiteoutLockup@2x.png/43608c988939.png)}}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logoGroup__{left:16px;position:absolute;top:6px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logoGroup__ .-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{position:static}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper__{margin:0 auto;max-width:1026px;padding:0 16px;position:relative}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ li{list-style:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__dropdown__,.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ .separator,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ .subtitle{display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__{border-right:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;width:220px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ ul{margin:0;padding:0}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__{margin:0 px;border:0;width:100%}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ ul{display:none}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__root__{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:1}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__root__{height:auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:78px;position:static}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto;margin:0 auto;position:relative;width:992px}@media screen and (min-width:991px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{height:100%}}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;height:auto;min-height:0;padding:0;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__nav__{float:left;height:100%;padding-right:0;pointer-events:initial;width:256px}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__nav__{float:none;display:block;margin:0!important;background:0 0;border:0;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #efefef;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0 16px 20px}@media screen and (min-width:991px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{border:1px solid #efefef;border-radius:3px}}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{width:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ .-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{padding:0 10px}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__{color:#262626;margin-left:205px;padding:30px 50px}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;padding:20px 0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__>:first-child{margin-top:0}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ a{color:#003569}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h1{font-size:32px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h2{font-size:24px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:12px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h3{font-weight:600;margin-bottom:12px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ li{padding-left:8px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ li:not(:first-child){margin-top:8px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ pre{white-space:pre-wrap}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__{color:#999;font-size:16px;font-weight:initial;margin:0;padding:16px;text-transform:uppercase}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__:first-child{display:block}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__:not(:first-child){display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__ i{float:left;width:22px;height:18px;margin-right:8px;margin-left:10px;background:url(/static/images/glyphs/disclosure-down@2x.png/9ae8409fbb3a.png) no-repeat center;background-size:14px 14px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__.active .-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__ i{-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);transform:rotate(180deg)}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:active,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:hover,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:visited{border-left:2px solid transparent;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;color:#262626;font-size:16px;display:block;padding:16px 16px 16px 30px;width:100%}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:hover{border-left-color:#dbdbdb}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__active__ .-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__{border-left-color:#262626;font-weight:600}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root__{font-size:12px;height:77px}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__{color:#262626;display:inline-block;float:right;font-weight:600;margin-top:20px;text-transform:uppercase}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav__{display:inline-block}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__{text-align:center;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__{margin:20px 0;padding:0;text-align:center}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ li{display:inline-block;list-style:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ li:not(:first-child){margin-left:15px}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:active,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:focus,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:hover,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:visited{color:#003569;font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper__{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;max-width:1026px;padding:0 20px}.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__{text-align:center}@media (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__{padding:100px 40px 0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__ a,.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__ a:visited{color:#003569}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__{background-color:#fff;color:#3897f0;border:1px solid #3897f0;border-radius:3px;display:inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;text-align:center;padding:8px;font:inherit;font-weight:700;width:90%}@media (min-width:736px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__{width:10%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__:active{opacity:.5}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__:focus{color:#1372cc;border:1px solid #1372cc}.-cx-PRIVATE-GatedContentPage__userAvatarContainer__{height:70px;text-align:center}.-cx-PRIVATE-GatedContentPage__userAvatar__{border-radius:50%;height:100%;width:auto}</style>



    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/static/scripts/jquery.js/a4e77326039e.js\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/static/scripts/bluebar.js/203583927eba.js\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>
</head>
    <body class=\" p-error dialog-404\" style=\"\">

            <div class=\"root -cx-PRIVATE-Page__root -cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__\">

                    <div class=\"page -cx-PRIVATE-Page__body -cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__\">


                                <header class=\"top-bar top-bar-new -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root__\">
    <div class=\"top-bar-wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper__\">
        <div class=\"logo -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__\"><a href=\"/\">Instagram</a></div>

        <div class=\"top-bar-left -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft__\">
            <ul class=\"top-bar-actions\">
                <li>
                    <a class=\"top-bar-home\" href=\"/\" label=Home><i></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


            <div class=\"top-bar-right account-state\" id=\"top_bar_right\">
                <ul class=\"top-bar-actions -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions__\">



                      <li id=\"link_profile\" class=\"link-signin -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn__\">
                          <a href=\"/accounts/login/\" class=\"loginLink\">
                              <i></i>
                              <strong class=\"-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText__\">Log in</strong>
                          </a>
                      </li>


                </ul>
            </div>

    </div>
</header> <!-- .top-bar -->




                        <div class=\"main -cx-PRIVATE-Page__main -cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__\">

    <div class=\"error-container -cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer -cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__\">


        <h2>Error</h2>

        <p>Please wait a few minutes before you try again.</p>


    </div>

                        </div> <!-- .main -->


                    </div> <!-- .page -->


                    <footer class=\"page-footer -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root__\" role=\"contentinfo\">
                        <div class=\"wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper__\">
                            <nav class=\"-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav__\">
                                <ul class=\"-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__\">
                                    <li><a href=\"/about/us/\">About us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"https://help.instagram.com/\">Support</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"https://about.instagram.com/blog/\">Press</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"/developer/\">API</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"https://about.instagram.com/about-us/careers\">Jobs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"/legal/privacy/\">Privacy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"/legal/terms/\">

                                          Terms

                                    </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                            <p class=\"copyright -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__\">&copy; 2021 Instagram</p>
                        </div>
                    </footer>


                <div id=\"reactModalMountPoint\"></div>
            </div> <!-- .root -->










        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
(function(){
  function normalizeError(err) {
    var errorInfo = err.error || {};
    var getConfigProp = function(propName, defaultValueIfNotTruthy) {
      var propValue = window._sharedData && window._sharedData[propName];
      return propValue ? propValue : defaultValueIfNotTruthy;
    };
    var windowUrl = window.location.href;
    var errUrl = err.url || windowUrl;
    return {
      line: err.line || errorInfo.message || 0,
      column: err.column || 0,
      name: 'InitError',
      message: err.message || errorInfo.message || '',
      script: errorInfo.script || '',
      stack: errorInfo.stackTrace || errorInfo.stack || '',
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      ref: windowUrl.indexOf('direct') >= 0 ? 'direct' : windowUrl,
      deployment_stage: getConfigProp('deployment_stage', ''),
      frontend_env: getConfigProp('frontend_env', 'prod'),
      rollout_hash: getConfigProp('rollout_hash', ''),
      is_prerelease: window.__PRERELEASE__ || false,
      bundle_variant: getConfigProp('bundle_variant', null),
      request_url: errUrl.indexOf('direct') >= 0 ? 'direct' : errUrl,
      response_status_code: errorInfo.statusCode || 0
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (window.__bufferedErrors && window.__bufferedErrors.length) {
      if (window.caches && window.caches.keys && window.caches.delete) {
        window.caches.keys().then(function(keys) {
          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            window.caches.delete(key)
          })
        })
      }
      window.__bufferedErrors.map(function(error) {
        return normalizeError(error)
      }).forEach(function(normalizedError) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/client_error/', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        request.send(JSON.stringify(normalizedError));
      })
    }
  })
}());
</script>
    </body>
</html>
", "headers": {"map": {"access-control-expose-headers": "X-IG-Set-WWW-Claim", "alt-svc": "h3-29=\":443\"; ma=3600,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=3600", "cache-control": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "content-language": "en", "content-length": "20776", "content-security-policy": "report-uri https://www.instagram.com/security/csp_report/; default-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; img-src data: blob: https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbsbx.com https://*.giphy.com; font-src data: https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com; media-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.fbcdn.net; manifest-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; script-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com wss://www.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob:; style-src 'self' https://*.www.instagram.com https://www.instagram.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://graph.instagram.com https://*.graph.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://api.instagram.com https://i.instagram.com https://*.i.instagram.com wss://www.instagram.com wss://edge-chat.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd blob:; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com; frame-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.instagram.com https://staticxx.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://web.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://m.facebook.com; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "cross-origin-embedder-policy-report-only": "require-corp;report-to=\"coep\"", "cross-origin-opener-policy": "same-origin-allow-popups;report-to=\"coop\"", "date": "Thu, 25 Feb 2021 03:59:51 GMT", "expires": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT", "origin-trial": "AuqWincgAuXeuu3KypEMnrrFEJHySaesyJS3EaIH40zvafzrU0Irhb7+5QwZpOqMZrPTjgvFl7Z5jJgy1dNAcQMAAAB6eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2luc3RhZ3JhbS5jb206NDQzIiwiZmVhdHVyZSI6IkNyb3NzT3JpZ2luT3BlbmVyUG9saWN5UmVwb3J0aW5nIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjEzNDExNjYyLCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZX0=", "pragma": "no-cache", "report-to": "{\"group\": \"coep\", \"max_age\": 86400, \"endpoints\": [{\"url\": \"/security/coep_report/\"}]},{\"group\": \"coop\", \"max_age\": 86400, \"endpoints\": [{\"url\": \"/security/coop_report/\"}]}", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000", "vary": "Accept-Language, Cookie", "x-aed": "38", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-fb-trip-id": "1679558926", "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN", "x-xss-protection": "0"}}, "request": {"_bodyInit": undefined, "_bodyText": "", "bodyUsed": false, "credentials": "same-origin", "headers": {"map": [Object]}, "method": "GET", "mode": null, "referrer": null, "signal": undefined, "url": "https://www.instagram.com/p/CK9OlOgK73g/?__a=1"}, "status": 429, "statusText": undefined}
```

Comment: Found the Instagram Graph APIs Rate Limiting [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/#instagram-graph-api). 
The issue should have been resolved after a while (maybe within 24Hrs since your first  429 response). 
Also the same piece of code worked for me at https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: A `429` code indicates there have been too many requests and the server is rate limiting you. Mostly in such cases you will see extra headers telling you when you can retry the request

Comment: @TarunLalwani can you give me an example by modifying the above code. It will be a great help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy yes it is working in Postman and Snack but not working in a real device environment.

Comment: When you do `console.log(error)` that object will have the response headers. See https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1388

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am getting headers but no idea how to handle it. Can you please share some working code snippet which can produce the correct response. It will be appreciated and a great help for me

Comment: Can you post the headers in your questions that you are getting in response?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have posted the headers in my question. Please help i am stuck on this issue since last week

Comment: Looks like the issue is occurring because the user is not logged in. Did you try making the request after logging in the user?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy no need to login for this, you can try the URL by pasting it on browser then you will get the response in json format

Comment: I get it, tried it before posting the first comment. My point was, the issue may be caused due to the same device being used repeatedly. Basically, the device can't make any more un-authenticated requests to the particular resource. I'm assuming it may be okay when changing the target id after each call, but that's just a guess.

Comment: No it is not the case here , i tried it on simulator as well as multiple android devices

Comment: Did you also try with different IP?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `User-Agent` to headers worked for me

For Example, Try This -

```
axios.post('https://www.instagram.com/p/CK9OlOgK73g/?__a=1', { headers: {
    "User-Agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0",
  } })
 .then(response => {
     console.log(response.data);
     // This will give you the desired response. It worked for me in an Expo Managed Project.
  })
 .catch((error) => {
     console.log('error');
  });
```

Remeber I am using `POST` request instead of `GET` request